# B2B LEX Order integration with external OMS - unit tests with OrderSummary

Tags: apex, b2b-commerce

We are working on a new B2B implementation for one of our clients. One of the tasks is to send the order data from B2B to the client's OMS. This is not SF OMS.

I am looking into the SF data model for B2B and I see there is an Order object and an associated Order Summary object. As I am quite new to SF, I am wondering which object I should refer to when sending the order data from SF B2B to OMS. I understand that order summary consolidates all the order information into a single view, so logically, it makes sense to use OrderSummary as the source of truth for order data in B2B.

From a high level, the data model for both objects looks very similar but there are certain fields which are missing from the order object like "BusinessModel" field & maybe others.

Additionally, it seems it is not possible to create a dummy OrderSummary object as part of testSetup apex test class method because ConnectAPI's can only be used with the seeAllData=true condition and this kind of violates the SF best practices. So, how is the community dealing with this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an official answer from Salesforce.

For B2B it is preferred to use the newly introduced `OrderSummary` object instead of the standard `Order` object.

Regarding unit tests, for now the only way to create an instance of orderSummary is to use `seeAllData=true`.This limitation is because of the usage of `ConnectApi`